# Asp.net Application Accessible to other machines

Tags: asp.net

I have application..its runnning on my localhost.. i need one more machine to access that application.. but when in tht link i type my IP address instead of localhost.. it showing cannot find server.. can you plz tell me steps what i need to do in orderr to access appplication to other machine.. as such there is no UAT server as of now...

Answer (score 2):

First off, make sure your firewall allows access through port 80.
Then, check if your IIS allows access from outside IP's.
I can help more if you provide this:

1. Your OS (XP, Windows 7, etc)
2. the local link to your app. Is there a port number needed to access the app?

LaterEdit: Ok, then you need to do this:
[image]

Now, your app will be served by IIS on port 80 (default). Check your firewall to allow traffic through this port.

If you IIS is set for another port, then use that one.
Checking the port in IIS:
[image]

Comment: this is my local link  http://localhost:2214/MainMenu.aspx and iam using XP, iam not sure it is accesing port no or not..

Comment: @deepti Then you can access your si application through port 2214 and as long your project is open in Visual Studio.

Comment: so wht link need to given http://localhost:2214/MainMenu.aspx instead of localhost my machine ip address.. tht i did but its not working

Comment: hold on, you need to give him the IP of your machine instead of localhost. something like this: http://192.168.0.123/MainMenu.aspx. Do you know your IP address?

Comment: yess i know but its not accessible   http://10.7.0.224/MainMenu.aspx   ,do i have to add a port

Comment: @deepti can you access your app like this? http://localhost/MainMenu.aspx. Also, you did not mention anything regarding the firewall on your machine...

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you are running the application from Visual studio which allows the localhost to run.

In order for your application to be available to other machines on the network, you have to ensure that IIS is installed on your development machine and then a website is set up for that application as well.

The application existing in IIS is what will make it accessible across your network.

Comment: neways there is firewaal issue si cant do that.. iam creating a deployment project for my application... but it get suucessfulyl deployed but i cant browse.. when i got to inetmgr to check there r no content files.. even thogut i add content files form setup project.. any idea.. why it is showing tht way

Comment: Usually when you create a 'website' it should be in your C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebsiteName Do you have any of your application files in that folder? If they don't exist there, then you can't see them. It's hard to tell if you have the files in the correct location based on what you posted.

In regards to your 'firewall issue' you should still be able to open ports on your local firewall that allows communication with port 80 across your local intranet. (Check your control panel -> Windows Firewall -> Advanced -> Local Area Connection, make sure HTTP is checked off).